# Rails 3, updated_at is 1 day ahead?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, ruby-on-rails-3

For some reason when updating a record, updated_at is getting updated as 2011-01-23, even though Date.today is returning 2011-01-22. Why are these different? Is there a way to set them to be the same?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, Rails uses UTC as the timezone for all `created_at` and `updated_at` fields. You can override this by setting a custom timezone in `config/application.rb`:

```
config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'
```

You can run `rake time:zones:all` from your application directory to get a list of all valid time zones.

Answer (score 1):

Did you set your time zone in the config/environment.rb file?

Comment: hmm, I definitely did not, how do I do that? (config.time_zone = 'EST' didn't work)

Comment: Time zone configuration goes into `config/application.rb`, not `config/environment.rb`.